# Decoding CDR problems

Tags: python, decoding, asn1tools

I need help with regards to decoding my this file. In this my code here when I tried to decode the `MTCallRecord I do see an empty { } in my save.txt file.

```
import asn1tools

# Compile ASN.1 schema
path_asn = 'cdr_schema.asn'
schema = asn1tools.compile_files(path_asn, codec='der')

# Input file path
file_path = 'b06044079.dat'

# Output file path
output_file_path = 'output_decode.txt'

with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
    bit_cdr = f.read()

# Decode the data
decoded_data = schema.decode('MTCallRecord', bit_cdr)

# Save the decoded data to a text file
with open(output_file_path, "w") as output_file:
output_file.write(str(decoded_data))
print(f"Decoded data saved to: {output_file_path}")
```

but when I change the type that I want to decode let's say for instance to `CallEventRecord` I get an error like this.

> "raise MissingMandatoryFieldError(member, offset)
> asn1tools.codecs.ber.MissingMandatoryFieldError: CallEventRecord.outGatewayRecord:"

If i also try to change the decoding to `CallEventDataFIle` i do get an output but almost all the data in the output file will still be encoded and not practically decoded.

I will definity appreciate it if assisted.
link to the asn file am using:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19dfbl6TUEZDNm61zEm8UEp3qNco8SoGH/view?usp=sharing
dat link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ibNekvIGXrmW7-bYENRBNMXkDwdNWDIJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you. **DO NOT** post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.